# Can not open Terminal and close XSERVER

Tags: nvidia, xserver

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked fine for the first couple of times then I started getting a error **system running on low graphics mode** and was not even able to login. I looked up on internet and tried installing the drivers but it wasn't quite working for me.
Then I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and followed a different procedure given by NVIDIA guys and for that.
I needed to close my X server and work on terminal for installing my NVIDIA graphic card drivers. But as soon as entered

```
$ init 3
```

I was getting this unstoppable flow of errors.
I thought it was some kind of Installation fault,so,  I have formatted my  laptop and have installed Ubuntu 16.04 . But nothing has changed.
I would be very glad if someone would help me out with this. I am pretty new to Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Try `sudo service lightdm stop` (from one of the CLI virtual terminals - Ctrl-Alt-F1 etc.) instead